# Examine TEB/TIB data when debugging with VS2010

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, internals

I've unsuccessfully tried to find a method to examine the Thread Environment Block (AKA Thread Information Block) when debugging native code with the Visual Studio 2010.

I know that `FS:[0]` should point at it, but the value in `FS` seems ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the pseudo variable, `@tib`.  You can put it in a watch expression or, more likely to be useful, put it in the Address box of a Debug + Windows + Memory window.

Also notable is the Windbg `!teb` command.  If gives you a formatted view of the TEB content.

Comment: Now that you've pointed at pseudo variables , I've looked for a complete reference and [found](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164891%28VS.100%29.aspx) that 'TIB' is documented ( It does however , works as I've checked )

Comment: Surely you meant it is *not* documented?  It is not afaik.

Comment: Of course (I've accidentally pre-post but Its seems to be too late to edit now) . It was actually supposed to be a request for a reference to all other undocumented pseudo variables , if such exist.